# How to save drag and drop to local storage?

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning JavaScript. There is a code that can move the block. But I can't save it in localStorage. Help!

```js
let drag = document.querySelector('.note');
drag.onmousedown = function(e) {
  let coord = getCoord(drag);
  let shiftX = e.pageX - coord.left;
  let shiftY = e.pageY - coord.top;
  drag.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.body.appendChild(drag);
  moveNote(e);
  drag.style.zIndex = 1000;

  function moveNote(e) {
    drag.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    drag.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + 'px';
  }
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveNote(e);
  };
  drag.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    drag.onmouseup = null;
  };
}

function getCoord(elem) {
  let main = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: main.top,
    left: main.left
  };
}
```

```css
.note {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to save the location of it (serialized as string)?

Comment: I want that when I move the block to any place on the page, after reloading the page, the block remains in the same place where I moved it.

Comment: @Alexander I'll show you how to save the coordinates in javascript.

Comment: @Parking Master how will you show me?

Comment: @Alexander see the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like very simple process.

On mouse up, get the `left` and `top` properties and save their values to localStorage:

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  localStorage.setItem("top", drag.style.top);
  localStorage.setItem("left", drag.style.top);
});
let coordinates = localStorage["top"] + "," + localStorage["left"];
if (localStorage["top"] && localStorage["left"]) {
  drag.style.top = coordinates.split(",")[0];
  drag.style.left = coordinates.split(",")[1];
}
```

Or the quicker way

```js
document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  localStorage.setItem("coordinates", drag.style.top + "," + drag.style.left);
});
let coordinates = localStorage["coordinates"];
if (localStorage["coordinates"]) {
  drag.style.top = coordinates.split(",")[0];
  drag.style.left = coordinates.split(",")[1];
}
```

Comment: I would like to show an example but I'm not allowed to for stackoverflow security reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much! The second way is what I was looking for. I did something similar, but without split and instead of drag.style.top and drag.style.left I set shiftX and shiftY.

Comment: @Alexander nice job!

Answer (score 1):

You can save the location using `localStorge.setItem("key", "value")` and load the item using `localStorge.getItem("key")`. So we save the JSON representation of our location object. We do that when mouse is up. But also not forgetting to load the value first on page load.

Note: This won't work in this sandbox environment.

```js
let drag = document.querySelector('.note');
drag.onmousedown = function(e) {
  let coord = getCoord(drag);
  let shiftX = e.pageX - coord.left;
  let shiftY = e.pageY - coord.top;
  drag.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.body.appendChild(drag);
  moveNote(e);
  drag.style.zIndex = 1000;

  function moveNote(e) {
    drag.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    drag.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + 'px';

    var position = {
      x: drag.style.left,
      y: drag.style.top
    }

    localStorage.setItem("last-position", JSON.stringify(position))
  }
  document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    moveNote(e);
  };
  drag.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    drag.onmouseup = null;
  };
}

function getCoord(elem) {
  let main = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: main.top,
    left: main.left
  };
}

window.onload = function() {
  var str_position = localStorage.getItem("last-position") || "{x:0, y:0}"
  var position = JSON.parse(str_position);

  drag.style.left = position.x;
  drag.style.top = position.y;
  drag.style.position = 'absolute';
  document.body.appendChild(drag);
  drag.style.display = 'block'
}
```

```css
.note {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="note">
</div>
```

Comment: And thank you very much! There is not enough knowledge yet to understand what to write. But now I will have different examples to see that the code can be bigger and more varied.